# Singular or plural verb with "class of proteins"

Tags: grammatical-number

Consider the following sentence:

> This table outlines a class of proteins that primarily **attack** the
>   brain.

I am not sure whether to use *attack* or *attacks*. If *attack* refers to *class* then I should use *attacks*, but if it refers to *proteins* then I should use *attack*.

In this case, both versions might work. However, I am not sure about this.

Comment: You are right. That targets the same issue but following this conversation I think both versions are possible.

Comment: Following **what** conversation?

Comment: What is doing the attacking? The class? or the proteins themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the sentence is ambiguous. *Attack* would imply that you're talking about a subset of all proteins that attack the brain (a class of them). *Attacks* would add a descriptor to the class, and be equivalent to

> This table outlines a class of proteins. The class primarily attacks the brain.

If the class encompasses all proteins that primarily attack the brain, I would use "attacks". Otherwise, both structures are valid, although I would lean towards describing the behaviour of the proteins themselves.